# How to create web services for uploading image in drupal 7

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal-7

Hello I am new in web services(Drupal 7) I want to know to create the web services for uploading images.I searched but could not find.I am using REST services.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Drupal to upload images**

Since Drupal 7 image handling is part of Drupal core, and there are responsive themes designed for smart phones, you don't need additional contributed modules to upload images from within drupal as a content contributor and your phone as a web browser.

Here is a short step by step:

1. Choose Administration > Add content > [Content type].
2. The image field will be displayed in the list of fields once you've
   added it to the content type (see above). Click 'Browse', then
   select and upload the desired image.
3. Enter alternate text to improve accessibility and optimize it for
   search engines.
4. Save the article.
5. Images can be added and removed from the node's Edit tab. If the
   node is deleted, all associated images are deleted with it.

**Using Android to upload images**

I believe this option would start as an architecture design decision and a price point. For example, you could use the Drupal Services module to open up REST and XML-RPC options from the drupal platform to your Android application. Next, you could choose to develop a native app for android to upload images into drupal's database for use in various applications. Or, you might consider a jQuery Mobile browser app that might be much simpler and less costly to build.

Two references:

Google I/O 2010 - Android REST client applications (to mate with Drupal's Service module) 1 hour video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Drupal 7 Mobile Web Development (A Beginner's Guide they jokingly claim), by Tom Stovall, Chapter 8: The Drupal Services Module for mobile apps): [http://www.amazon.com/Drupal-Mobile-Development-Beginners-Guide-ebook/dp/B007K7UL2S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007K7UL2S)

Comment: Thanks for replying me.But I want to create the web service not any content.I add the image field in signup form.I want to upload the image from Android apps and save in the database.

Comment: I found this link. Maybe you can use it to start your project and then ask a more specific question as your development proceeds? http://bitgriff.blogspot.com/2013/02/drupal-with-android-integration-make.html